# Restarting docker container in swarm mode

Tags: docker

I am running a docker service in swarm mode. When I want to restart it, there are 2 options I know:

1. from swarm manager: `docker service scale myservice=0` then `docker service scale myservice=1`
2. from server running the server: `docker ps`, take the container id of my service and do `docker stop <containerId>`

And this works fine. However, if I go with option #2 and instead of `docker stop` I write `docker restart` it will restart the current instance, but because being in swarm mode it will also start a new one. So in the end I will end up having 2 of the same service, even though in my compose I have specified I want only 1 replica.

Is there any way to prevent `docker restart` and the docker swarm to start a 2nd service while one is already there?

I am using docker 18.09.2 on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: did you try [service update](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_update/) `docker service update --force SERVICE_NAME` this will force re-create containers for your services, note that it will re-create the containers not restarting them.

Comment: @Ma'mounothman surely I can also do that. But what I am trying to achieve here is to prevent the start of 2 intances in case `docker restart` is used directly on the container